# Vsftpd не логинится root пользователь

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

Vps ubuntu 16.04:
В системе есть root, и user пользователи. Установил vsftpd. Обычный пользователь конектится нормально, но права у него есть только на его папку, рут вообще не конектится.
Я хочу редактировать файлы через sftp, но у обычного юзера не достаточно прав. Вопрос в том, как можно дать полные права юзеру? Что б редактировать системные файлы. Или как сделать что бы root конектился через sftp?

Comment: Эм... может я что-то путаю, но `sftp` - это `openssh-server`. Там другой конфиг.

Comment: @don Rumata возможно я что то не то установил) что мне тогда установить, что бы через фаилзиллу редактировать редактировать файлы?

Comment: `sudo aptitude -y install ssh`. В файлзилле потом подключаешься со своим пользователем и паролем от системы по протоколу `sftp`.

Comment: Ssh установлен. В фаилзилле обычный user конектится нормально, но я им не мону редактировать файлы конфигураций и тп. Вот как мне дать права на чтение и запись файлов обычному user-у

Comment: Костыль: `passwd root`, разрешить в `sshd_config` логиниться под рутом, собственно логиниться в рута и править конфиги. ОЧЕНЬ несекурно, но работает.

Comment: А почему для редактирования нужен `sftp`? Почему это не делается на самой машине через ssh+nano\vim\emacs?

Comment: @donRumata не удобно мне в консольном редакторе работать. Гораздо удобнее открыть файл через sftp, внести изменения и залить обратно

Comment: Ну тогда попробуй костыль. Но это неправильно.